# Trying to save contents of contentEditables in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Doing a project to learn React, where you can press a button and create little sticy notes to edit. What I want to do is save the edits made to a component in the array that maps all the components.

My code is below:

```
function Note({id, content, onWrite}){
  return (
    <Draggable bounds="parent" axis='both' onChange={e => onWrite(id, content)}>
      <div className='note'>
        <p contentEditable="true">{content}</p>
      </div>
    </Draggable>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  function handleOnChange(key, content){
    console.log('A note was changed');
  }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>
        <button onClick={() => {
          setNotes(
            [
              ...notes,
              {id: uuid(), content: 'Type something'}
            ]
          );
          console.log(notes);
        }}>+</button>
        <div className="notes">
          {notes.map((note, index) => {
            return(<Note key={note.id} content={note.content} onWrite={handleOnChange}></Note>)
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

(I want to save it into the array because I want to make it a full stack app to teach myself, and I figured that saving into an array will make it way easier)

I tried using an even handler for onChange using some tutorials, but the test run to make it log that a change took place didn't work, and I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is best practice but if it's for learning should be good. And in the context of contentEditable I think its probably no worse. Generally you would want to use input wherever possible.

You can use `onChange` or `onInput` events to provide some callback to perform whatever actions you want when the input is changed. For inputs in general, if its react `onChange` behaves like `onInput` basically, otherwise `onInput` fires whenever content is changes (user types) and `onChange` when element loses focus.
But when it comes to contentEditable I think `onInput` is only thing that will work, not sure why but seems `onChange` does not get called.

`onInput` callback gives you event argument which contains `innerText` field you can use as an argument for `onWrite` which you provided.

So you can write

```
onInput={(e) => onWrite(e.currentTarget.innerText)}
```

Then where you render the notes

```
onWrite={(value) => handleOnChange(note.id, value)}
```

And in change handler

```
    setNotes((notes) =>
      notes.map((note) => (note.id === key ? { ...note, content } : note))
    );
```

to update the note.

I don't know where this falls in the context of controlled vs uncontrolled components, probably somewhere in-between which is not ideal. You'll get react warning.

But here's a link to code [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-jn976x?file=/src/App.tsx) with it working.

Comment: Tried it, but now I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') for the div that holds the notes